# ember data debug model deserialisation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember application that is getting its data from a REST API.

I have a particular model *contacts* that is not being processed correctly.

There are no error messages such as you get if you spell the model name wrong.
The payload for the index route contains about 1500 contacts like so:

```
{"contacts":
   [{"id":1,
     "type":"customer",
     "foreign_key":1242,
     "first_name":"John",
     "last_name":"Smith",
     ...
     "created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
     "updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
     "customer_id":1242
    },
     ...
   ]
}
```

The JSON response looks OK when I look in the *Network* tab. The browser is able to parse and display the response nicely.

I have compared the response to similar models and the format looks the same to me.

In the ember inspector, under *Data* I get 1 contact with id=null and other fields undefined.

The contact model is:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  type:           DS.attr('string'),
  foreign_key:    DS.attr('number'),
  first_name:     DS.attr('string'),
  last_name:      DS.attr('string'),
  ... more strings 
  created_at:     DS.attr('string'),
  updated_at:     DS.attr('string'),
  customer:       DS.belongsTo('customer')  
});
```

ember 2.0.2
ember-data 2.0.0
using pod structure

How can I investigate further? It looks like the response is not being parsed and turned into *contact* models properly.

***ANSWER***

It turns out that you shouldn't use `type` as one of your field names in the model.
(I should have gone with the small warning bell that I heard when defining my DB table... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the `normalizeArrayResponse` in your Application Serializer, and debug like so:

```js
normalizeArrayResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
  console.log(payload);
  return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, normalizedRecords, id, requestType);
}
```

Just to confirm your data is going through the serializer.

Comment: thanks for that, I get `Object {contacts: Array[1357]}`

Comment: Meaning you get an array from your endpoint. You could `console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));` to see it in JSON format. Why are you getting 1357 contacts, isn't that a lot?

Comment: it's a lot ... I've cut it down to 200 for now... what is the point of converting to JSON, that's what it arrived as in the first place ... all looks fine to me at this point ... however I only get 1 undefined contact in Ember inspector under Data...

Comment: The point is just to be able to see the contact in json string, to easily debug, nothing more. The thing you're clear about now is that your contacts are actually entering the serializer, you can perhaps set a breakpoint here in chrome devtools and start debugging to find out why they don't enter your store. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors are thrown... I figured it out though ... the model had a field called `type` in it which clashes with an internal variable.